# Compiling error in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am at the end of this project and I am getting this compilation error that I cannot figure out. It's driving me nuts, I was reading that it could be an issue with a linking error between classes. But I can't figure out where it could even be and how to fix it.

```
> CruiseShip.o: In function `CruiseShip':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:8: multiple
> definition of `CruiseShip::CruiseShip(std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
> std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >, int)' CargoShip.o:/home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:8:
> first defined here CruiseShip.o: In function `CruiseShip':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:8: multiple
> definition of `CruiseShip::CruiseShip(std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
> std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >, int)' CargoShip.o:/home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:8:
> first defined here CruiseShip.o: In function
> `CruiseShip::setPass(int)':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:12: multiple
> definition of `CruiseShip::setPass(int)'
> CargoShip.o:/home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:12:
> first defined here CruiseShip.o: In function `CruiseShip::getPass()':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:15: multiple
> definition of `CruiseShip::getPass()'
> CargoShip.o:/home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:15:
> first defined here CruiseShip.o: In function `CruiseShip::print()':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:20: multiple
> definition of `CruiseShip::print()'
> CargoShip.o:/home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/CruiseShip.cpp:20:
> first defined here main.o: In function `main':
> /home/013/w/wn/wna130030/Assignment5_test/main.cpp:18: undefined
> reference to `CargoShip::CargoShip(std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
> std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >, int)'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [app] Error 1
```

**CruiseShip.h**

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H_
#define CRUISESHIP_H_
#include <string>
class CruiseShip: public Ship{
protected:
    int maxPassengers;


public:
    CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers);
    void setPass(int);
    int getPass();
    virtual void print();

};
#endif
```

**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "CruiseShip.h"
using namespace std;



CruiseShip::CruiseShip(std::string name,std::string year, int maxPassengers):Ship(name,year){
maxPassengers=0;
}

void CruiseShip::setPass(int maxPassengers){
    this->maxPassengers=maxPassengers;
}
int CruiseShip::getPass(){
    return maxPassengers;

}

void CruiseShip::print(){
    cout<<"The name of the ship is "<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"The capacity of the ship is "<<maxPassengers<<endl;

}
```

**Ship.h**

```
#ifndef SHIP_H_
#define SHIP_H_
#include <string>
class Ship{
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string year;

public:
    //Default Constructor
    Ship(std::string name, std::string year);   
    void setName(std::string name);
    void setYear(std::string year);                 
    std::string getName();
    std::string getYear();
    virtual void print();


};

#endif
```

**Ship.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
using namespace std;

Ship::Ship(string name, string year){
name="";
year = "";

}

void Ship::setName(string name){
this->name = name;
}
void Ship::setYear(string year){
    this->year=year;
}
string Ship::getName(){
    return name;
}

string Ship::getYear(){
    return year;
}

void Ship::print(){
    cout<<"The name of the ship is "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"The year the ship was built is "<<year<<endl;
}
```

**CargoShip.h**

```
#ifndef CARGOSHIP_H_
#define CARGOSHIP_H_
#include <string>
class CargoShip: public Ship{

protected:
    int cargoCapacity;


public: 
    CargoShip(std::string name, std::string year,int cargoCapacity);
    int getCapacity();
    virtual void print();

};

#endif
```

**CargoShip.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "CruiseShip.h"
#include "CargoShip.h"

using namespace std;


CargoShip::CargoShip(int cargoCapacity):Ship(name,year){
    this->cargoCapacity=cargoCapacity;

}

int getCapacity(){
    return cargoCapacity;
}
void print(){
cout<<"The Name of the ship is "<<getName()<<endl;
cout<<"The ship's cargo capacity is "<<cargoCapacity<<endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "CruiseShip.h"
#include "CargoShip.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i;
//An array of Ship pointers
Ship *ships[3]={
new Ship("Lolipop", "1960"),
new CruiseShip("Disney Magic","2010",2400),
new CargoShip("Black Pearl","2003",50000)
};
//Display output
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
ships[i]->print();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What command are you executing to produce that error text?

Comment: Psychic debugger says: CruiseShip.cpp and CruiseShip.cpp are in your make file twice

Comment: *"I am at the end of this project"*   That is funny.   When you are compiling, and have a bunch of link errors, you are no where near the end.  I'd say you're less than 1/2 way to done.

Comment: You have missed few parameters from the constructor of  CargoShip in cargoship.cpp file, thats why you are getting that last error undefined
    reference toCargoShip::CargoShip..

Comment: in addition: no virtual destructor in the base class Ship and your Ship constructor is wrong, it should initialize with the passed arguments

Comment: If you were to really complete your project, you should clean up the memory leaks.  And when you do that, you're going to get undefined behavior due to `Ship` not having a virtual destructor.

Comment: use override when you override virtual functions, it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your CargoShip.cpp you have a few functions where you have forgotten the class name in front:

```
int getCapacity(){
    return cargoCapacity;
}

void print()
{
  cout<<"The Name of the ship is "<<getName()<<endl;
  cout<<"The ship's cargo capacity is "<<cargoCapacity<<endl;
}
```

should be

```
int CargoShip::getCapacity() // you may want to add const here too
{
  return cargoCapacity;
}
```

...

You also include both Cruiseship.h and CargoShip.h in CargoShip.cpp for some 
reason.

Some other things:

Your constructors seem a bit off, use them to initialize the member variables

```
Ship::Ship(string name, string year)
{
  name="";
  year = "";
}
```

should be

```
Ship::Ship(string name, string year)
{
  this->name=name;
  this->year = year;
}
```

and preferably use other names for the arguments to avoid `this->`

I see no virtual destructor in your Ship class, this is needed otherwise when you delete your objects you encounter serious problems.

It is also better style to include the base class in your derived class headers. That way when a user uses your derived class header he does not need to know what header to include before.

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H_
#define CRUISESHIP_H_
#include <string>
#include "Ship.h"                        <--
class CruiseShip: public Ship
{
```

When you return values from a function that does not modify the member variables declare it const:

```
...
int getPass() const;   
...
```

It is good style when you declare an array like this that you clean it up as well when you are done with it

```
//An array of Ship pointers
Ship *ships[3]={
new Ship("Lolipop", "1960"),
new CruiseShip("Disney Magic","2010",2400),
new CargoShip("Black Pearl","2003",50000)
};

... 

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  delete ships[i];
}
```

btw that is when the right destructor will be called due to the virtual destructor.

Comment: Adding the destructor fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many many mistakes in your code because of a lack of knowledge in C++. I'll try to explain the mistakes in your `Ship` files.

Ship.h

```
#ifndef SHIP_H_
#define SHIP_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Ship{
private: // should be private because you just want your class to access them
    std::string name;
    std::string year;

public:
    /* default constructor because this is what is walled when you just create a variable like : Ship ship1;*/
    Ship();

    Ship(std::string, std::string);    //constructor with parameters
    // SETTERS
    void setName(const std::string);
    void setYear(const std::string);
    //GETTERS
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getYear() const;

    virtual void print() const; // virtual class
};

#endif
```

Ship.cpp

```
#include "Ship.h"

using namespace std;

Ship::Ship(){
    name="";
    year="";
}

Ship::Ship(string name, string year){
    this->name=name;
    this->year = year;
}
// SETTERS
void Ship::setName(const string name){
    this->name = name;
}
void Ship::setYear(const string year){
    this->year=year;
}

// GETTERS
string Ship::getName()const{
    return name;
}

string Ship::getYear()const{
    return year;
}
void Ship::print()const{
    cout<<"The name of the ship is "<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"The year the ship was built is "<<getYear()<<endl;
}
```

A const function tells the program that it CANNOT modify the variable. The getters shouldn't modify the class parameters. In your example it's obvious, but it is a good way to do to force it. Const variables is the same, the variable you are passing in parameters CANNOT be modified.

There are 4 different constructors that exist. The default one isn't the same as the constructor with parameters. And the constructor with parameters is here to  overwrite the parameters of the class by the parameters.

For cargoShip, when you declare `CargoShip(std::string, std::string,int)` you se 3 parameters, string,string and int. When you are using it you have to call the function withe the same name and the same number and kind of parameters or it will not call the same function :

```
CargoShip::CargoShip(string name, string year,int cargoCapacity):Ship(name,year){
    // Ship constructor is called givind the parameters name and year
    this->cargoCapacity=cargoCapacity;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{

    Ship *ship=new Ship("Lolipop", "1960");
    CruiseShip *cruiseShip=new CruiseShip("Disney Magic","2010",2400);
    CargoShip *cargoShip=new CargoShip("Black Pearl","2003",50000);
    //Display output

    Ship *ships[3]={ship,cruiseShip,cargoShip}; // THIS is a really bad way to do it

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        ships[i]->print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me :

```
The name of the ship is Lolipop
The year the ship was built is 1960
The name of the ship is Disney Magic
The capacity of the ship is 0
The ship's cargo capacity is 50000
```

Comment: It seems like my ship.cpp & ship.h compile fine, and the compiler is throwing an error for CruiseShip though?

Comment: It's not because it doesn't throw error that there isn't . It'll throw errors after or when you are going to launch the application.  I gave you sample of how to write proprely, just look at what i gave you first

Comment: Okay, I appreciate it man.

Comment: Your main is quite horrible because `Ship *ships[3]={
new Ship("Lolipop", "1960"),
new CruiseShip("Disney Magic","2010",2400),
new CargoShip("Black Pearl","2003",50000)
};` doesn't mean anything. You should overload operator= first.. i'll edit my answer

Comment: tell me if you don't have the same outputs than me, because I gave a lot of my time in that. Try to learn what I changed

Comment: I added a virtual destructor to my ship.cpp class and it fixed it.

Comment: you can't just try adding * or virtual or anything everywhere til it works. This isn't how you program . But i hope i helped

Comment: I got the same output as you! =]

Comment: No you did man, there was other changed I made according to what you said. But when I added the virtual destructor it fixed the crazy compile error.

Comment: I did not use a virtual destructor, so I hope an error won't show up. Try to learn why it works and what is a virtual destructor. Learn from your mistakes. As batman's father said we fall so that we can learn to pick ourselves up ;)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in CargoShip.cpp, a few of your implementations are missing CargoShip::

eg

```
int getCapacity(){
    return cargoCapacity;
}
```

should be

```
int CargoShip::getCapacity(){
     return cargoCapacity;
}
```